# Firebase createUser with Parse User data

Tags: firebase

I'm migrating my Parse App due to the shut down. Is there anyone who has the experience of migrating from Parse to Firebase. 
I know I need to design a new data model, but what bothers me is the user data which contains bcrypt salted password. So I was wondering if I can use the sdk to createUser with account(email) and salted password since both Parse and Firebase use bcrypt to hash password.

Comment: In general, you've got two items to send to firebase to create a user or login; username(email) and password. If you know the users existing passwords, you could obviously just use Firebase createUser to create the users with the known password. However, if the password is already encrypted, and that's all you have access to, then you'd be sending createUser a string which would then be encrypted again by Firebase. So the answer is probably no as you need a clear text password to create the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase can't do an import yet.

There is a migration guide for running a Parse server on GCP: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/frameworks/parse-server

In theory, while the password is plain text in the server you might be able to create a user account and password on Firebase, and slowly populate the current user accounts that way (somewhat like the slow migration strategy here: [How to design system to allow migration of encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692561/how-to-design-system-to-allow-migration-of-encryption)).

Comment: So I have to implement the new user register process to get users input their password first, and do a data migration based on the email, right?

Comment: Yeah, the slow migration strategy can take a long time, so to speed it up you should e-mail your users asking them to log in or change their passwords.